# Is safe to call NetworkStream.BeginWrite multiple times from one thread?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, tcpclient

I am implementing a TCP client in my Unity3D game and I am wondering if it's actually safe or not to call the NetworkStream.BeginWrite without waiting until the previous call finishes writing.

From what I understood while reading the documentation, it's safe until I am not performing concurrent BeginWrite calls in the different threads (and Unity has only one thread for the game main loop).

For my reading I call BeginRead right after making a connection with the asynchronous callback in which I read the incoming data from the TcpClient.GetStream(), put it to the separate MemoryStream with lock(readMemoryStream), and run BeginRead again. Besides that, in my Update() function (in the main game thread) I check for the new data in the readMemoryStream, check for the solid message and unpack it (using the same lock(readMemoryStream) of course) and perform operations on the game objects based on the message from server.

Will this approach work fine? Won't BeginRead interfere with BeginWrite? 
Again, I am using callback thread to read the data and main thread to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as no two threads are calling `BeginWrite()` *concurrently*, all is well. The same thread, or even other threads, can call `BeginWrite()` consecutively before earlier calls have completed.

Do note that the completion callbacks *might* be executed out of order; if you do implement it this way and the order of the execution of the completion callbacks matters, it is up to you to keep track of which asynchronous operation is which. Of course, for writing to the socket, this often doesn't matter, as you may not have anything to do in the completion callback other than to call `EndWrite()`.

Reading from and writing to a socket are completely independent operations. The socket is full-duplex and can safely handle concurrently pending read and write operations on the same socket.

You didn't ask, but like `BeginWrite()`, you can also call `BeginRead()` multiple times without earlier operations completing. And again, as with `BeginWrite()`, it's up to you to keep track of the correct order of the operations so that when your completion callback is executed for each one, you know which order the received data should be in.

Note that since the order of the completions is critical for read operations (something often not the case for write operations), it is common for all but the largest-scale implementations to never overlap read operations on a given socket. The code is much simpler when for a given socket, only one read operation is in progress at a time.

One last caveat: do note that your buffers are pinned for the duration of the I/O operation. Too many outstanding I/O operations can interfere with the efficient management of the heap, due to fragmentation. This is unlikely to be an issue in a client implementation, but a large-scale server implementation should take this into account (e.g. by allocating large buffers so that they come from the LOH, where things are always pinned anyway).